# Core Location didEnterRegion method can not work with more than one regions

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, location

I'm working on a project about location based reminder. I have used `CoreLocation`'s `didEnterRegion` method. so when I set a location for entering region, I can take a notification but whenever I want to set another location for entry with `didEnterRegion` method it only see first one. The method cannot be called for second location. Could you help me?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit


class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let latitude1: CLLocationDegrees = 78.98
        let longitude1: CLLocationDegrees = 90.09
        let center1: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude1, longitude1)
        let radius1: CLLocationDistance = CLLocationDistance(100.0)
        let identifier1: String = "Notre Dame"

        let currRegion1 = CLCircularRegion(center: center1, radius: radius1, identifier: identifier1)

        let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 20.2020
        let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = 2.2945
        let center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let radius: CLLocationDistance = CLLocationDistance(100.0)
        let identifier: String = "Notre Dame"

        let currRegion  = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: identifier)

        locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        currRegion1.notifyOnEntry = true
        currRegion.notifyOnEntry = true

        locationManager.delegate=self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: currRegion1)
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: currRegion)
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        if region is CLCircularRegion {
            handleEvent(forRegion: region)
        }
    }

    func handleEvent(forRegion region: CLRegion!) {
        print("Geofence triggered!")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official document:

> You must call this method once for each region you want to monitor. If
>   an existing region with the same identifier is already being monitored
>   by the app, the old region is replaced by the new one.

So make the different identifier:

```
//...
        let identifier1: String = "Notre Dame1"
//...
        let identifier: String = "Notre Dame2"
//...
```

Comment: thank you so much. If i want to take their identifier in this method how can i do this? In method it cannot be called.

Comment: Use "if region.identifier == "Notre Dame1" {" to check which region is got in. And it's better to define global constants for identifiers to improve coding elegance.

Comment: You are welcome. And please set my answer as the accepted answer if it's helped, that could help increase my reputation, thanks. ;)